# If $1<a<b$, which of the following is larger than the other: $a\sqrt[3]{b^2}$ and $b\sqrt[3]{a^2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given that  $1<a<b$, how can you determine which is the larger, out of $a\sqrt[3]{b^2}$ and $b\sqrt[3]{a^2}$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write $a = \sqrt[3]{a^3}$, $b = \sqrt[3]{b^3}$, and use  properties of the cube root that you know.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun will do next time. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

We have

- $x=a\sqrt[3]{b^2}\implies x^3=a^3b^2=a(ab)^2$
- $y=b\sqrt[3]{a^2}\implies y^3=b^3a^2=b(ab)^2$

and recall that $f(x)=x^3$ is strictly increasing that is

$$x_1<x_2 \iff x_1^3<x_2^3$$

Answer (score 2):

It is $$a\sqrt[3]{b^2}<b\sqrt[3]{a^2}$$ if $$a^3b^2<b^3a^2$$ if $$a^2b^2(b-a)>0$$ and this is true.